# How many times would i have to flip a coin to determine bias?

Tags: statistical-significance, bias

I want to be clear because there are a few similar questions but none of the answers really answer my question (or im just not smart enough to make it work). The question is, HOW MANY FLIPS. My understanding is that im looking for a sample size but i don’t know how to calculate it.

So, let’s said i found a coin and had a suspicion that it was biased. How many times would i have to flip the coin to determine with 95% confidence that the coin was biased?

Comment: There's no way to know, because it depends on how strongly the coin is biased.  If it is two-sided, for instance, then six flips will do; but if it has a 50.1% chance of heads, the number of flips to detect that (intuitively, and correctly) must be very great.  Thus, to have an answerable question you need to assume (or guess from other data) what the bias might be.  Do any of the answers you found address this case?

Comment: @whuber if we take the example of 50.1% chance of heads as the bias, could you show the calculation to determine the number of flips?

Comment: This is done in several threads here on CV.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21691/power-calculations-sample-size-for-biomarker-study/21773#21773, for instance.  You can find more by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=binomial%20sample%20size%20power)